# PHP, APACHE - C Program

Tags: php, c, apache

Server version: Apache/2.4.52 (Fedora Linux)
*

> PHP 8.0.14 (cli) (built: Dec 16 2021 03:01:07) ( NTS gcc x86_64 )
>
> Copyright (c) The PHP Group Zend Engine v4.0.14, Copyright (c) Zend
> Technologies
> with Zend OPcache v8.0.14, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
>
> Above are the current versions for Apache and PHP on Fedora 35 running
> on 5.15.13-200.fc35.x86_64

I have a webserver and DNS server running on local machine. Previously on Fedora 33 the webserver's PHP scripts executes an external custom C binary using 'shell_exec' command.

However, post upgrade to Fedora 35, the 'shell_exec' only executes system commands and no external programs.

I suspect it to be SELinux, but could not find any details on it.

Any supporting point to enable PHP's shell_exec or exec commands to execute custom C program would be much helpful.

Thanks in advance
Nethaji